# Is it possible to make a number string with using one variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch coding, but this is a problem I can't figure out how to solve. What I want it to do is make it only use one variable, like this:

```
@echo off
:string
set /a one+=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1
(string code here)
set /a times+=1
if %times% equ 5 goto tell
goto string

:tell
echo Numbers: %string%
```

The output would be like this:
Numbers: 5 2 4 2 3

I have been messing around with %RANDOM% but I was wondering if this is possible. One last thing is that I made it so it would prompt you have many numbers would be in the string, so if there are no shortcuts there would be an obscure amount of code. For example:

```
set /a varone=1
set /a vartwo=2
set /a varthree=6
set /a varfour=3
set /a varfive=9
[...]
```

I tried making it so it would automatically make and set variables. I was able to make the variables but I couldn't put them into a string. The code was something like this:

```
@echo off
:start
set /a g+=1
set /a va%g%r=%RANDOM% * 5 / 32768 + 1
set /a times+=1
if %times% equ 5 goto tell
goto start

:tell
(This is where I got stuck)
```

I tested it and I know it can make and set variables. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET /p "count=How many numbers ? "
SET /p "limit=Range 1.. ? "

SET "string="
:another
SET /a selection=1+(%random% %% %limit%)
SET "string=%selection% %string%"
SET /a var%count%=selection
SET /a count-=1
IF %count% gtr 0 GOTO another

ECHO string=%string%
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

This is a primitive way of solving your problem.

It assumes that the user-input is sensible - a positive integer, not `xyz` for instance.

The string produced in `string` will have a trailing space.

```
set "string=%string:~0,-1%"
```

would strip off that space.

The random-selection is slightly skewed unless `limit` is a power of 2 - and `%random%` is not perfectly random.

-- improved version

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

SET /p "count=How many numbers ? "
SET /p "limit=Range 1.. ? "

SET /a maxrand=32767 - (32768 %% %limit%)

SET "string="
:another
SET /a myrand=%RANDOM%
IF %myrand% gtr %maxrand% GOTO another
SET /a selection=1+(%myrand% %% %limit%)
SET "string=%selection% %string%"
SET /a var%count%=selection
SET /a count-=1
IF %count% gtr 0 GOTO another

ECHO string=%string%
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: How would you get a perfectly random number?

Comment: Perfection comes at a price. The modified code improves the distribution by rejecting any value generated by `%random%` that biases the result, assuming `%random%` is perfectly random. A random-number uses a "seed" value to generate the number. sequence. Same seed=>same sequence. Winbatch uses the time as a seed, so run at the same time of day=>same sequence. The UK had a lottery-like system called "Premium bonds" where prizes are awarded by a computer at random, but the choice is made by using a "white noise" generator as a source of random numbers.

Comment: This might not get read but would it be possible to reverse the string output? For example instead of it being "7 3 8" it would be "8 3 7". I was just wondering if it's possible, but if not the other code still works great!

Comment: Change `SET "string=%selection% %string%"` to `SET "string=%string% %selection%"` Note however that the final result in `string` will have a leading space, you would need to `ECHO string=%string:~1%` (see `set /?` from the prompt for docco)